# Собрать рабочий APK в Unity3D

Tags: android-sdk, unity3d

При компиляции самого простого приложения - вращающийся куб, сборка проходит успешно, получаю APK весом в 18МБ, закидываю на реальный телефон, устанавливаю, запускаю - ориентация экрана применяется (горизотальная, как и хотел), фон становится чёрный (собственно, ожидаю хоть что-то), но приложение сворачивается и висит в процессах. Любая попытка переключиться на процесс даёт чёрный фон длительностью ~0.5 секунд, и приложение снова сворачивается.

На каких этапах я допустил ошибки? Ведь, судя по документации, я выполнил все пункты.

Объясню что у меня есть и что использовал:

1. Следуя документации поставил Android Studio
2. Открыл Android SDK, установил нужные пакеты
   [image: Список выбранных операционок]
   Чтобы было понятно, поставил ВСЁ, для выбранных версий, в том числе и образы для эмулятора:
   [image: Подробный список операционок]
   Установил все инструменты и обновления:
   [image: Список инструментов]
3. Далее, по новой выкачал юнити (при установке я не учитывал что буду работать с андроидом), поставил инструменты для компиляции под андроид. Всё успешно работает.
4. Создаю новый проект, называю Box, режим - 3D, без ассетов.
5. Добавляю куб, пишу скрипт на шарпе - вращение по времени. (одна строчка)
6. Изменяю настройки проигрывателя, устанавливаю идентификатор приложения, минимальный уровень API 14 - Ice Cream Sandwich
   [image: Настройки Player]
7. Сохраняю сцену. Добавляю её в список сцен с индексом 0.
8. Выполняю сборку
   [image: Сборка проекта в APK]
9. Достаю телефон, открываю настройки, раздел "для разработчиков", соглашаюсь на "установку сторонних приложений".
10. Полученный APK передаю на телефон. Там открываю и устанавливаю.
11. Запускаю приложение - никаких ошибок, программа висит 1 сек с чёрным фоном и сворачивается. Процесс работает, могу переключиться на него - но, всё по кругу - чёрный фон, затем сворачивается. Никаких сообщений.

Пытался менять минимальный уровень API до 5.0 и до 2.3 - всё одно, та же самая проблема. Скинул APK знакомому, у него планшет под KitKat - та же ерунда, программа просто сворачивается без ошибок, и висит в фоне.

Телефон - дешёвый "Билайн Смарт 4", характеристики:

- Операционная система - Android 5.0 (Lollipop)
- Процессор - Четырехъядерный МТК 6582M 1,3 ГГц
- Экран - IPS, мультитач, 4,5 дюйма, 480*854; цветной 16М
- Память - ПЗУ 8ГБ + ОЗУ 1 ГБ, поддержка MicroSD до 32 ГБ

Что это может быть и как нужно настроить Unity/AndroidSDK, чтобы элементарное приложение с кубом собиралось и работало корректно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, из-за третьего пункта:

> Далее, по новой выкачал юнити (при установке я не учитывал что буду работать с андроидом), поставил инструменты для компиляции под андроид. Всё успешно работает.

повредился контент юнити. Компилируемый проект просто неправильно собирался...

Полное удаление и повторная установка Unity исправила ошибку. Приложение успешно собралось.